# How to check if PaymentRequest API is supported by browser within Typescript code

Tags: angular, typescript, browser, payment-request-api

Is there a way to force typescript's `window` object to resolve `PaymentRequest` property? Here is code example I have inside my angular component:

```
if (window.PaymentRequest) {
  // This browser supports Payment Request
} else {
  // Browser does not support Payment Request
}
```

And here is an error I get:

`error TS2339: Property 'PaymentRequest' does not exist on type 'Window'.`

Comment: Can you upgrade to TS 3.6? It's been added to the window type here.

Comment: No, it's not an option currently :(

Comment: This indicates that PaymentRequest is provided by --lib dom. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/paymentrequest
Can you add DOM to your compiler options?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options.

## Ideal : Update TypeScript

Update to latest TypeScript as it ships with the definitions: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/20e2be1e1a0fb2a2f481410d24e4cae915e5ece7/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L11549

## Not Ideal 1: Add a local definition

Add a `global.d.ts` in which you extend `interface Window` to have the corresponding API, copy pasting from lib.d.ts mentioned above.

> Not ideal as you will be doing a lot of copy paste that someone else will have to revert in the future if they decide to upgrade TypeScript.

## Not Ideal 2: Just use an assertion

```
if ((window as any).PaymentRequest) {
```

> Not ideal as assertions are [potentially little white lies to the compiler](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html).

Comment: Thanks, @basarat. Seems like ideal option is not applicable currently, but Not Idial # 2 will work for now :)